# Shared Codepen link looks weird on twitter

Tags: html, css, twitter, flexbox

So I created some [codepens](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/) and shared them on Twitter. When you do that, Twitter creates an image of that pen. But let's make an example:
This is how it should look like:
[image: How it should look like]
and this is how it looks on twitter:
[image: How it looks]

For that pen I used flexbox, like this:

```
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Why does that occur? Are some CSS tags (like the flexbox ones) not supported of that "image frame"? And how can I adjust that it looks fine? Just avoid using flexbox?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: one reason could be that the pen is not responsive.

Comment: @Hash You can drag the browser window to like 500px width until it starts looking weird. In height, the overflow just gets hidden.